# Passing arguments to rolling_apply

Tags: python, pandas

I am in need for passing several arguments to my target function for [pd.rolling_apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_apply.html)

My target function looks like this:

```
  def complexFunction(i,j,k,l,verbosity=False):
    ...
    return 0.0
```

Are the arguments positional? What is the canonical way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_apply.html#pandas.rolling_apply) (that you have linked) , you can use the `args` keyword to pass the arguments, the first argument would be passed in by the `rolling_apply` , you can define the rest of the arguments as a tuple and pass it into `args` keyword argument. Example -

```
 pd.rolling_apply(df,<window>,complexFunction,args=(j,k,l))
```

Example/Demo -

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],columns = ['A','B','C'])

In [8]: def func(i,j,s):
   ...:     print(i,j,s)
   ...:     print('next')
   ...:     return i
   ...:

In [9]: pd.rolling_apply(df,1,func,args=(1,2))
[ 1.] 1 2
next
[ 4.] 1 2
next
[ 2.] 1 2
next
[ 5.] 1 2
next
[ 3.] 1 2
next
[ 6.] 1 2
next
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually make my functions take a row as its single input eg.

```
  def complexFunction(row,verbosity=False):
    i = row.i
    j = row.j
    k = row.k

    return 0.0

  pd.rolling_apply(df, complexFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way using `partial` from `functools`.

```
from functools import partial

def complex_function(data, x, y):
    # some calculations
    return sum(data) * x * y

my_partial_func = partial(complex_function, x=2, y=5)

ser = pd.Series(np.arange(10))
pd.rolling_apply(ser, window=5, func=my_partial_func)

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    100
5    150
6    200
7    250
8    300
9    350
dtype: float64
```