# pandas rolling_apply TypeError: int object is not iterable"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function saved and defined in a different script called *TechAnalisys.py*  This function just outputs a scalar, so I plan to use pd.rolling_apply() to generate a new column into the original dataframe (`df`). 
The function works fine when executed, but I have problems when using the `rolling_apply()` application.This link [Passing arguments to rolling_apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799585/passing-arguments-to-rolling-apply) shows how you should do it, and that is how I think it my code is but it still shows the error "TypeError: int object is not iterable" appears

This is the function (located in the script  TechAnalisys.py)

```
def hurst(df,days):
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    df2 = df[-days:]    
    rango = lambda x: x.max() - x.min()

    df2['ret'] = 1 - df.PX_LAST/df.PX_LAST.shift(1)
    df2 = df2.dropna()    
    ave = pd.expanding_mean(df2.ret)
    df2['desvdeprom'] = df2.ret - ave
    df2['acum'] = df2['desvdeprom'].cumsum()
    df2['rangorolled'] = pd.expanding_apply(df2.acum, rango)
    df2['datastd']  =   pd.expanding_std(df2.ret)
    df2['rango_rangostd'] = np.log(df2.rangorolled/df2.datastd)
    df2['tiempo1'] = np.log(range(1,len(df2.index)+1))
    df2 = df2.dropna()
    model1 = pd.ols(y=df2['rango_rangostd'], x=df2['tiempo1'], intercept=False)
    return model1.beta
```

and now this is the main script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import TechAnalysis as ta

df  = pd.DataFrame(np.log(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(100000)+1)+1000),columns =['PX_LAST'])
```

The following works:

```
print ta.hurst(df,50)
```

This doesn't work:

```
df['hurst_roll'] = pd.rolling_apply(df, 15 , ta.hurst, args=(50))
```

Whats wrong in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the `type` of `df` within the `hurst` function, you'll see that `rolling_apply` passes it as `numpy.array`.

If you create a `DataFrame` from this `numpy.array` inside `rolling_apply`, it works. I also used a longer window because there were only 15 values per array but you seemed to be planning on using the last 50 days.

```
def hurst(df, days):
    df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['PX_LAST'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    df2 = df.loc[-days:, :]
    rango = lambda x: x.max() - x.min()

    df2['ret'] = 1 - df.loc[:, 'PX_LAST']/df.loc[:, 'PX_LAST'].shift(1)
    df2 = df2.dropna()

    ave = pd.expanding_mean(df2.ret)
    df2['desvdeprom'] = df2.ret - ave
    df2['acum'] = df2['desvdeprom'].cumsum()
    df2['rangorolled'] = pd.expanding_apply(df2.acum, rango)
    df2['datastd']  =   pd.expanding_std(df2.ret)
    df2['rango_rangostd'] = np.log(df2.rangorolled/df2.datastd)
    df2['tiempo1'] = np.log(range(1, len(df2.index)+1))
    df2 = df2.dropna()
    model1 = pd.ols(y=df2['rango_rangostd'], x=df2['tiempo1'], intercept=False)
    return model1.beta

def rol_apply():

    df = pd.DataFrame(np.log(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(1000)+1)+1000), columns=['PX_LAST'])
    df['hurst_roll'] = pd.rolling_apply(df, 100, hurst, args=(50, ))


      PX_LAST  hurst_roll
0    6.907911         NaN
1    6.907808         NaN
2    6.907520         NaN
3    6.908048         NaN
4    6.907622         NaN
5    6.909895         NaN
6    6.911281         NaN
7    6.911998         NaN
8    6.912245         NaN
9    6.912457         NaN
10   6.913794         NaN
11   6.914294         NaN
12   6.915157         NaN
13   6.916172         NaN
14   6.916838         NaN
15   6.917235         NaN
16   6.918061         NaN
17   6.918717         NaN
18   6.920109         NaN
19   6.919867         NaN
20   6.921309         NaN
21   6.922786         NaN
22   6.924173         NaN
23   6.925523         NaN
24   6.926517         NaN
25   6.928552         NaN
26   6.930198         NaN
27   6.931738         NaN
28   6.931959         NaN
29   6.932111         NaN
..        ...         ...
970  7.562284    0.653381
971  7.563388    0.630455
972  7.563499    0.577746
973  7.563686    0.552758
974  7.564105    0.540144
975  7.564428    0.541411
976  7.564351    0.532154
977  7.564408    0.530999
978  7.564681    0.532376
979  7.565192    0.536758
980  7.565359    0.538629
981  7.566112    0.555789
982  7.566678    0.553163
983  7.566364    0.577953
984  7.567587    0.634843
985  7.568583    0.679807
986  7.569268    0.662653
987  7.570018    0.630447
988  7.570375    0.659497
989  7.570704    0.622190
990  7.571009    0.485458
991  7.571886    0.551147
992  7.573148    0.459912
993  7.574134    0.463146
994  7.574478    0.463158
995  7.574671    0.535014
996  7.575177    0.467705
997  7.575374    0.531098
998  7.575620    0.540611
999  7.576727    0.465572

[1000 rows x 2 columns]
```